# Merge two collection with specific fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, collections, merge, foreign-keys, aggregate

I have 2 collection, issues and repos.

> issues : issue_id, body, **full_name**, ...
>
> repos : repo_id, title, **full_name**, ...

I want to add "***repo_id***" field to issues collection. (with foreign field full_name)

After this process desired output collection;

> issues2: issue_id, body, **full_name**, **repo_id** ...

```
db.getCollection("issues").aggregate([
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: "repos",
         localField: "full_name",    // field in the orders collection
         foreignField: "full_name",  // field in the items collection
         as: "fromissues"
      }
   },
   {
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$fromissues", 0 ] }, "$$ROOT" ] } }
   },
   { $project: { fromissues: 0 } },
   {$out: "issues2"}

])
```

I can use this query to merge 2 collection with whole fields.
How can select only repo_id field? 
I tried to change this row but it didnt work.

```
{ $project: { "id":1, "full_name":1} },
```

If I use project, I must add to project "all columns of issues collection" + repo_id + full_name

```
{ $project: { "id":1, "body":1, ...(24 fields)... "repo_id":1 "full_name":1} },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not use {$out: "issues2"} keyword in query

```
     db.store.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: "testers",
          let: { item: "$fullName" },
           pipeline: [
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$fullName",  "$$item" ] },
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              },
              { $project: { repo_id: 1 } }
           ],
         as: "fromissues"
      }
   },
   {
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$fromissues", 0 ] }, "$$ROOT" ] } }
   },
   { $project: { 'fromissues': 0 } },

])
```

Comment: if I didnt use out it didnt update collection. It just shows results.

Comment: Please tell what you want

Comment: Besides, must i add all of columns into $project row?. I want to add only one field.

Comment: Your solution didnt worked without "out" parameter. You can try it.

Comment: Ok you want to add column add in store table

Comment: Please tell me mongoose version??

Comment: Please now check query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203923/discussion-between-mahesh-bhatnagar-and-babeyh).